# Cartesian components of electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields

my book gives this formula for electric field:

[image]

and then says that on the axes we have:

[image]

but I haven't understood where does those formulas come from...
I think it's something like :

$\vec{E}(\vec{r})= \frac {1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {Q_i}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r_1}|^3} ( \vec{r} - \vec{r_1}) $

but

$( \vec{r} - \vec{r_1}) = (x-x_1) \widehat{i} +(y-y_1) \widehat{j}+(z-z_1) \widehat{k}$

then

$\vec{E}(\vec{r})=  \frac {1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {Q_i}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r_1}|^3} [(x-x_1) \widehat{i} +(y-y_1) \widehat{j}+(z-z_1) \widehat{k}]$

$\vec{E}(\vec{r})=  \frac {1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {Q_i}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r_1}|^3} (x-x_1) \widehat{i} +  \frac {1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {Q_i}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r_1}|^3} (y-y_1) \widehat{j} +\frac {1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {Q_i}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r_1}|^3} (z-z_1)\widehat{k}$

with

$\vec{E_x}(x,y,z)=  \frac {1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {Q_i}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r_1}|^3} (x-x_1) \widehat{i} $

$\vec{E_y}(x,y,z)= \frac {1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {Q_i}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r_1}|^3} (y-y_1) \widehat{j} $

$\vec{E_y}(x,y,z)= \frac {1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {Q_i}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r_1}|^3} (z-z_1)\widehat{k}$

Am i wrong?

p.s. I left $|\vec{r}-\vec{r_i}|^3$ but I know that i should calculate it to have the same denominator of my book.

Comment: why is this off topic? " should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem". The specific concept is the electric field, and  the effort is the demonstration i've tried to give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely right. The denominator in your expression is the same as denominator in answer. You just need to calculate magnitude of $|\overrightarrow{r}-\overrightarrow{r_i}|$ , which is exactly $\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2+(z-z_i)^2}$.